# Why is Active Directory so big and confusing?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, ldap

Am I the only person who feels this way? Active Directory is a staple in business networks and it clearly provides some important services like single sign on and DNS integration and directory services, and so on. So I can see why it is used widely. I'm just wondering, with all of the terminology and objects in the model, Forests, Trees, One-way trusts, Federations, AD Replication, Bridgeheads, Transports, et al, are they all necessary to describe an enterprise network and its hosts? I feel like a lot of the terminology involved is totally specific to AD and doesn't really have a parallel in the open source or *nix world. Is Active Directory an unnecessarily complex product, is it a little bit more complex than it needs to be, or do I just not understand what it is used for? Forgive me if this is a bad question but whenever I look at articles like [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816619(WS.10).aspx) I just get this deflated feeling that this should not be so complicated. Am I totally out of line?

Comment: This will likely be closed since it's not a question.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol

Comment: This is completely off topic.

Comment: For the same reason the world economy is so big and confusing. Because it is what it is. Note that economics is not confusing to an economist, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's no more confusing than it has to be. If you have a single site with a single domain, you don't need to worry about bridgeheads, forests, trees, trusts, transports. If you have multiple sites, multiple domains, then you need the features that those terms refer to. It's certainly no more complex than similar products like eDirectory (Netware's NDS), which has its own terminology